# Heroku cli.rb:24 Undefinded Method error_with_failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have been using Heroku successfully for some months now, but clearly I have made a change somewhere that is causing a number of problems.

While the command "heorku version" executes, pretty much any other command, such as "heorku db:push -t mytable" fails with the error message:

.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:24:in `rescue in start': undefined method`error_with_failure' for Heroku::Helpers:Module (NoMethodError)
        from C:/Users/Doug/.heroku/client/lib/heroku/cli.rb:10:in `start'
        from c:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku:33:in`'

Taps gets loaded and detects the Heorku database, but that's as far as it gets.

Added info:
1) Windows 7 64 bit
2) Paths appear to be correct.
3) "Heroku version" displays "heorku-gem/2.28.8 (imingw32) ruby/1.9.3"
4) There appears to be a more current version of toolbelt (2.32.x) that automatically checks for client updates, but when I install it, I end up with my current version (2.28.8)

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.
Doug

Comment: I managed to generate a partial solution. I removed the .heroku/client directory and reran "heroku update".  This now provides the most current verison of heorku.

Comment: But using "heroku db:push -t mytable" still generates and error: "Failed to connect to database  Sequel::AdapterNotFound -> LoadError cannot load such file -- mysql

Comment: Since the original problem is basically solved, I'm saying this is closed.  I don't have enough reputation points to close it out....? so I gave it a vote instead. Hopefully this is proper protocol.